# Sync of two PostgreSQL databases maintained separately for an application

Tags: postgresql, synchronization, postgresql-9.2

I made a backup of a database used for an application as we are upgrading its features into a new version. The old application and new application are running separately with separate databases.

According to the requirement, we now need to sync all the users between both databases. The problem is that there are many dependent tables in both databases. What would be the best approach to sync the databases?

Any help in this regards is very helpful.

Edit

At the starting our application was with the older version when we upgrading it to the newer version with new design, we have took the backup of our old database and started new one with this old database. In the mean we have continued running both the applications, new users joined in the older version even after releasing the newer site.So now both the applications continued for quite some time, the user base is increased from both the sides now as per the requirement we should combined both the databases and should close the old application one.

Here user table is linked with several other tables which maintain their subscription plans, their profiles, their gaming count ..etc

Comment: what about [dblink postgres](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dblink%20postgres) or [Foreign data wrappers](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=foreign%20data%20wrapper%20postgresql)

Comment: Hi Vivek, Thanks for the reply, but we are not using any dblink because, I was not trying to use two databases at a same time, I want to sync two databases of same database structure but contains different data. In other words i want to combine both the databases into one.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is a dead link

Comment: Need more info about your environment

Comment: Can you explain what the dependent tables are? For instance, is this about multiple tables linking user accounts to user data? Please elaborate your question if you want to good answer that applies to your situation.

Comment: _i want to combine both the databases into one_ > be more specific on this, do you want to Merge DB A to B or create new DB C using A and B or you want get output just by querying both DBs ?

Comment: Hello Patrick, I have edited my question now. This is about combining two databases came from the single one but as time lapse, both the databases got to their peaks, Now I have to combined both these databases to the single one.

Comment: Yes Vivek, I want to merge both the DBs into one "C" using "A" and "B"

Comment: Close-voting as too broad because there's no generic way to reconcile data from tables that have diverged in independant databases. Each table may require a different merge strategy depending on unique constraints and FK constraints.

Comment: *new users joined in the older version even after releasing the newer site.So now both the applications continued for quite some time*. Um. **oops**. You'll need to write *application-specific code* to do this, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Given that these are different versions of the application and may have different table schemas over time, I think your best option is to `COPY` all of the necessary tables from each side, process them off-line, and then load the new rows using an external utility.

In theory you can do all this from inside the database, and could even use Bucardo of FDW's but a major problem you will have in these cases is the fact that this becomes brittle if the schema of the new application changes.